# Different results on using sqrt() and pow() functions

Tags: c++, c

I was solving Euler problem no. 10 that asks to find sum of all primes below 2million.
I am getting different results on using `sqrt` and `pow` functions.
Using `sqrt` gives the correct answer, plus using pow function takes more time. Here is my code.

```
for(sum=0,i=3;i<=2000000;i+=2)
{
    for(j=3;j<=sqrt(i);j++)
        if(i%j==0)
            break;
    if(j>sqrt(i))
        sum+=i;
}
sum+=2;
std::cout << "\nSum = " << sum;
```

Comment: How are you using `pow`? Show us your code.

Comment: And what is the problem with `pow()`?

Comment: `pow(i,0.5)` in place of `sqrt(i)`
And using `pow()` gives a wrong answer and takes longer time.

Comment: Your code is missing two pairs of curly braces and a `break` statement. `pow` or `sqrt`, you get a wrong value either way.

Comment: Also you did not ask anything, what result does each of your program give?

Comment: It is the basic algorithmic part that I have mentioned here.

Comment: using `sqrt()` gives 142913828922 in about 15 seconds
while using `pow()` gives 142985215325 in about 20 seconds

Comment: same results on using `0.5f`

Comment: I get the correct result from both, `sqrt` in about 2.25s, `pow` in about 15.25s (g++ 4.7.2). Looks like the compiler hoists out `sqrt`, but not `pow`.

Comment: What are `sum` `i` and `j`, `int`s? @DanielFischer Of what type did you declare them for it to work?

Comment: @Djon I made `sum` a `long` (needs more than 32 bits), `i` and `j` declared as `int`. (By the way, clang gives the same times for `pow` as for `sqrt`.)

Comment: @DanielFischer maybe the optimization level, what did you use?

Comment: @Djon No optimisations, and `-O3`. All produce the same (correct) result with both compilers.

Comment: @sh94 What platform are you on, and what compiler did you use?

Comment: I can't test it now, but since it works for you I'd have to assume it has something to do with OP's compiler and library. Can we have more information on your setup @sh94?

Comment: I am on windows 7 professional, 32-bit and the compiler is GNU GCC and using codeblocks 12.11

Comment: @DanielFischer `long` isn't always longer than 32 bits...

Comment: You might want to look up the sieve of Eratosthenes if you're interested in a quicker way to solve this problem.

Comment: @rubenvb I know (that's why I specifically said it needs more than 32 bits), but on my box, it is, so I used that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `sqrt(x)` *should* be faster and more accurate than `pow(x,0.5)`, why do you think it's in the library?  Second, you're probably getting a wrong answer because your loop termination condition is testing a floating-point number. A tiny round-off somewhere in one of those 2 million loops is probably enough to throw off the total. Finally, you're calculating a floating point sqrt() twice inside each iteration of the loop, which is terribly slow.

Instead of

```
for (j = 0; j <= sqrt(i); ++j)  . . .
```

try

```
limit = (int)(sqrt(i) + 0.5);
for (j = 0; j <= limit; ++j) . . .
```

Comment: Thanks alot sir, your answer was a great help to my concepts :)

Answer (score 1):

I can not reproduce your problem on my computer, but your testing on `double` is a very dangerous one. If `i` is the square of a prime number you are relying on high precision of the `sqrt` and `pow` to have the correct result. Maybe on your system there is a slight rounding difference on one or more of such squares. You'd better test `j*j <= i` and `j*j > i`.

Comment: Whoa! that was 8 times faster than using `sqrt()` and it gave correct answer too.

Comment: This isn't entirely true.  His use of `sqrt` is fine; it will return exact results when given square floating-point numbers.

Comment: @tmyklebu I trust you are correct that `sqrt` should give precise enough results. I would still discourage people to rely on equality of `double` types, unless they really know what they are doing.

Comment: @BryanOlivier:  I wouldn't.  Knowing what you can do with floating-point, when it works, and how to do it is pretty important.  You aren't born understanding this stuff; you need to learn it through experience.  Project Euler is a pretty good way to get some low-risk experience with your tools.

Answer (score 0):

`pow` is very difficult to implement correctly --- that is, so that things like `pow(x*x, 0.5)` returns `x` for those `x` where that's the right answer.  Very few implementations (CRlibm being a notable exception) implement `pow` correctly.

`sqrt`, on the other hand, is guaranteed to be correctly rounded by the IEEE specification, and that's why your code works with `sqrt` and not with `pow`.

Comment: I am sorry your answer is too technical for me to understand.

Comment: @sh94: Floating-point numbers are basically numbers in a binary "scientific notation" that have a set precision.  (There are a couple of other vagaries, but I'll ignore them.)  Basically, all I'm saying is that it's OK to rely on `sqrt` to do the right thing, but it's not OK to rely on `pow` to do the right thing.